# Linux C++ Qt fixing "QIODevice::write: ReadOnly device"?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qobject, qfile

So the problem is, I am trying to write to a file with QFile but i am getting the error:

```
QIODevice::write: ReadOnly device
```

My implementation looks like:

```
void logList::insert(QString data) {
    QString lin;
    QFile file1("log.data");
    file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream out("log.data");
    lin = out.readLine();
    out << data;
    file1.seek(30);
    file1.close();
}
```

I have also tried with

```
QIODevice::ReadWrite
```

for the open()

and

```
system("chmod 777 log.data");
```

So how do I read and write from a file in linux?

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks a bit odd.  You have a `QFile` named `file1` but you only ever `open`, `seek` and `close` with it -- you never write.

Answer (score 2):

```
QTextStream out("log.data");
```

The `QTextStream` constructor that takes a string does not open the file, or work on a file opened with that name.

Instead, you should pass the `QFile` object to `QTextStream`

```
QTextStream out(&file1);
```

In addition, if you want to read from the file, this won't work

```
file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
```

You need to use the `QIODevice::ReadWrite` flag, instead of `QIODevice::WriteOnly`

Finally, if you're using `QTextStream` instead of QFile's read / write functions, it would be better to [seek with the `QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#seek), rather than the QFile object

```
out.seek(30);
```